# Abstract function have dynamic return type - C#

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I am trying to have an abstract function return a List of a custom data type during run time.

//Abstract class: Integr

```
abstract public List < object > getRefills();
```

//Implementation in derived class: TMTStandard

```
public override List < TMTStandardRefill > getRefills()
{

    List<TMTStandardRefill> refills = db.TMTStandarRefills.ToList();
    return refills;

}
```

//I call the function to bind my data to a gridview data source

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = integr.getRefills();
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have looked at Generics but was unable to come up with a solution.

Comment: What error did you get with the above approach?

Comment: C# does not support return type covariance on virtual overrides.

Answer (score 2):

Make `Integr` a generic of `T`:

```
public abstract class Integr<T>
{
    public abstract IList<T> GetRefills();
}

public class TMTStandard : Integr<TMTStandardRefill>
{
    public override IList<TMTStandardRefill> GetRefills()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```